# Qwt installation for Qt Creator on windows 7

Tags: qt, windows-7, installation, qt-creator, qwt

I installed Qt Creator. I would like to use Qwt. I downloaded and unzipped to "C:\qwt-6.1.0" folder. I performed the following instructions:

`qmake qwt.pro`
`mingw32-make`
`mingw32-make install`

There is no error. Everything is fine. But I don't know how I can integrate with Qt creator. I would like to use Qt via form editor. How can I install plugin?

Thanks

**Platform**
*Windows 7*


**Versions**
*Qt Creator 2.7.2

Qt 5.1.0(32 bit)

Qwt 6.1.0*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/53787-HowTo-Installation-of-Qt-5-0-1-and-Qwt-6-1-0-rc3-(Win7-64bit)

check this.Its works also on win8 64 bit.